# jQuery detect if browser support Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I check if the browser supports the Zoom css atribute? I know from Caniuse.com that only Firefoz does not support it, so, from this question ([In Javascript, how do I determine if my current browser is Firefox on a computer vs everything else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324944/in-javascript-how-do-i-determine-if-my-current-browser-is-firefox-on-a-computer))  I tried:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla) { ...
```

which returns me an error in chrome:

```
Cannot read property 'mozilla' of undefined
```

Another solution according to the answer is detectinf if the browser supports that function, how could I do that?

Comment: jQuery's `$.browser` has been deprecated and removed, as browser detection is generally a bad idea. You want feature detection instead.

Comment: The real question is, why not just use [scale](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) instead

Comment: Scale has it's own problems, like blurring, zoom works better for Chrome and IE but I'll make firefox use scale

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you could detect support for a CSS feature in plain JavaScript. (Replace zoom with whatever feature is needed.)

```
document.createElement("detect").style.zoom === ""
```

**2023 Edit**: Just validated this again 7 years since writing it. The solution still works. And it's still the case that some browsers support this feature, and others don't.

That said, one newer browser (KaiOS) is now on the scene — which is just one more reason to detect features not browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I think this answer should help you : [jquery determine if css zoom is available in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729454/jquery-determine-if-css-zoom-is-available-in-browser)

The best way is to use a JS library dedicated to test browser CSS capabilities like Modernizr does.